# Rename a file using php show permission denied

Tags: php

I am using XAMPP 5.6.30-0. Mac OSX 10.11.6

I am using php to help me to do annotation to images. This is the purpose of my code.

1. Run through a folder and get all the filenames of images;
2. Show the first picture;
3. Press one of the two buttons, and change the filename and moving it to another folder

This is my code

```
<?php

    $images_list = scandir("images_raw",1);
    $image = $images_list[0];

?>
<br>
<img src="images_raw/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="girl 01">

<form>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="C_">Complete</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="NC_">Not Complete</button>
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
        $result = $_GET['submit'];
        $new_filename = $result.$image;
        $root = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $origpath = $root."images_raw/".$image;
        $destpath = $root."annotated_images/".$new_filename;
        rename($origpath, $destpath);
    }
?>
```

However, the rename() returns

> Warning: rename(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/phplessons/annotator/images_raw/KMK-18-
>   00032_2.jpg,/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/phplessons/annotator/annotated_images/C_KMK-18-00032_2.jpg): Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/phplessons/annotator/annotator_ver2.php on line 34

Can anyone point out what is the problem?

Comment: It's a permission issue.  You will have  to look at the directory annotated_images to see if it has EVERYONE who can add / write / edit

Comment: @Forbs Or better still if the account that the web server runs under has those permissions. No need to give these permissions to everyone

Comment: it is a folder in localhost

Comment: @RiggsFolly that's true, I am assuming since it is XAMPP, it's a personal web server not something outward facing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, my solution was to change the file owner using `chown`. I was using Apache, so I changed the file owner to www-data:www-data and it worked fine. Also check the permissions of the file using `chmod`. Google both of those commands for better understanding

Comment: I try both but unfortunately, I got operation not permitted when running chown and chmod. Still cannot figure out how to solve this problem.